# Accidentally formatted a drive with an important pst-file in it. How to recover?

Tags: data-recovery, format, pst

I did a quick format and windows 7 installation on a client computer without knowing that the computer contained archived emails. So when I learnt that the computer had these important files I pulled out `Recuva` and scanned the drive. Then I extracted the pst-files, but of course they were corrupt.

I tried to recover them with scanpst but it just stopped working or did't find anything. I tried some other software as well but it did not work.

So am I totally our of hope here or is there something else I should try?

Comment: @Hello71 Yes, I stopped everything immediately. THe only thing that has run since is recuva

Answer (score 5):

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is perhaps able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Best recovery software there is
[GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm)

Comment: +1 I love this software as long as someone pays me a license. I also have to recover formatted data and I was able to find it all right but can't recover without a license. */angry/* For a one time only usage 95€ seems waaaay too expensive. And they don't offer any discounts...

Comment: What is your data worth?

Comment: I can live without it but would be nice to have it back...

Answer (score 1):

> So am I totally our of hope here or is there something else I should try?

First thing you should try is to restore from your latest backup. It's so easy to do, and presto! Your data is there.

Answer (score -1):

Try Recuva, Its a free file recovery program. Personally, I would pay for Recover it All or something like that, but if you want to be cheap, try freeware first.

Comment: Wow, almost 2 years and 8-odd months after he posted his question you suggested the exact same program he already used?